# Implementint View.isInEditMode()

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I forked Apollo recently from CyanogenMod project for experimenting, this app uses custom views for theming mainly. I am usung AndroidStudio an this IDE requires custom views to implement View.isInEditMode() method to bypass context loading when editing layout.

So I have something like this:

```
public class CustomButton extends ImageButton
    implements OnClickListener, OnLongClickListener {

private final SomeUtililtyClass mResources;

public CustomButton(final Context context, final AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    // Handle editing layout from IDE
    if(!isInEditMode()) {
        mResources = new SomeUtililtyClass(context);
        // do more stuff
    }
    // some methods
}
```

Problem is that i have some methods that use mResources that is not always initialized giving me a Java compiler error.
There is an standard way to handle this or should I initialize mResources to null or an empty object?
It is necesary to remove the final modificator?

Answer (score 0):

There's not really a standard way or tricks, it's up to you.

`View.isInEditMode()` returns true when your class is instantiated under the IDE (the class is really executed), so it's a run-time method rather than a compiler-known value.

In the case you propose, initializing to `null` and removing `final` would do it, seems simple. Or maybe,if you want to keep the `final` keyword, you can pass a `NULL` context tho the `SomeUtilityClass` constructor if `isInEditMode()` and make it just return without executing the conflicting operation.

In my experience, normally doing in the first line of the constructor

```
if (isInEditMode()) return;
```

is enough for most classes. But if your class does custom drawing (`onDraw` / `draw` / `dispatchDraw`) you'd need to check it there as well.

At the moment it looks like Eclipse doesn't process click handlers, but this can change in the future.